# How do you get table-formatted output from MySQL in non-interactive mode?

Tags: mysql

I like the table output that the mysql client program produces in interactive mode, but if I try to run a sql script like this:

```
mysql -uroot mydb < myscript.sql
```

I only get tab-separated output.

```
mysql -uroot mydb -e 'select * from mytable'
```

does produce the output in the desired table format, however.

How can I get the first command to produce table-formatted output? I don't want HTML output, but the terminal character output with aligned columns and headers.

Comment: Thanks for posting, I needed the same thing. I use the term 'non-interactive' mode for this too, but I don't know if it's a widely use term. I wonder if this form of execution (i.e. straight from a shell) has any other names - batch mode?

Answer (score 12):

Add the `-t` option to mysql (table).

```
  mysql -t -uroot mydb < myscript.sql

  mysql -t -uroot mydb -e 'select * from mytable'
```

Answer (score 6):

Use \P less -S option before running the query

```
mysql> \P less -S
```

PAGER set to 'less -S'

Comment: The answer on your blog is very short; you have basically included the entire thing here, so linking to your blog, too, seems spammy. Also, you did not disclose that it's your blog you linked to. I have removed the link; please read the FAQ on Self Promotion before posting any further links to your blog. You can put your blog link in your profile here; Stack Overflow is not meant to be advertisement for your blog via answers, though.