# Column width of mysql output

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

The output of an mysql command doesnt correctly align the titels (using script).
Here is the sql command in script.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo "select * from hw_inventory "| mysql --host=localhost --user=root --database=monitor > /tmp/inventory
```

This gives me following output in /tmp/inventory

```
ip_address      entity_index    entity_physname entity_physdesc entity_serial
10.212.0.1      1000    Switch 1        WS-C3850-12S    FOC1842U117
10.212.0.1      1009    Switch 1 - Power Supply A       Switch 1 - Power Supply A       LIT18300URD
10.212.0.1      1010    Switch 1 - Power Supply B       Switch 1 - Power Supply B       LIT183506NH
10.212.0.1      1034    Switch 1 FRU Uplink Module 1    2x1G 2x10G Uplink Module        FOC18363NJX
```

As you cen see the alignment (tabs) is not in the same way as the text with Switch 1 should start under entity_physname.
It needs to be like following output:

```
ip_address      entity_index    entity_physname              entity_physdesc            entity_serial
10.212.0.1      1000            Switch 1                     WS-C3850-12S               FOC1842U117
10.212.0.1      1009            Switch 1 - Power Supply A    Switch 1 - Power Supply A  LIT18300URD
10.212.0.1      1010            Switch 1 - Power Supply B    Switch 1 - Power Supply B  LIT183506NH
10.212.0.1      1034            Switch 1 FRU Uplink Module 1 2x1G 2x10G Uplink Module   FOC18363NJX
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: How about `echo "select * from hw_inventory "| mysql -t --host=localhost --user=root --database=monitor > /tmp/inventory`. You shoud look at this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693240/how-do-you-get-table-formatted-output-from-mysql-in-non-interactive-mode).

Comment: Thanks! That solves my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For formatting the output from the mysql use the `-t` param

```
"select * from hw_inventory "| mysql -t --host=localhost --user=root --database=monitor > /tmp/inventory
```

Comment: Please make sure that you search the stack overflow well before posting questions. Many of your questions might already have an answer in SO.